# How to compute correclty cross validation scores in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a classification task. Nevertheless, I am getting slightly different results:

```
#First Approach
kf = KFold(n=len(y), n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=False)
pipe= make_pipeline(SVC())
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

print ('Precision',np.mean(cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision')))



#Second Approach
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print ('Precision:', precision_score(y_test, y_pred,average='binary'))

#Third approach
pipe= make_pipeline(SCV())
print('Precision',np.mean(cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=kf, scoring='precision')))

#Fourth approach

pipe= make_pipeline(SVC())
print('Precision',np.mean(cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=kf, scoring='precision')))
```

Out:

```
Precision: 0.780422106837
Precision: 0.782051282051
Precision: 0.801544091998

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1431                                               train, test, verbose, None,
   1432                                               fit_params)
-> 1433                       for train, test in cv)
   1434     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
   1435 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    798             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    799             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 800             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    801                 self._iterating = True
    802             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    656                 return False
    657             else:
--> 658                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    659                 return True
    660 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    564 
    565         if self._pool is None:
--> 566             job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
    567             self._jobs.append(job)
    568             self.n_dispatched_batches += 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __init__(self, batch)
    178         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    179         # arguments in memory
--> 180         self.results = batch()
    181 
    182     def get(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, error_score)
   1522     start_time = time.time()
   1523 
-> 1524     X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
   1525     X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
   1526 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _safe_split(estimator, X, y, indices, train_indices)
   1589                 X_subset = X[np.ix_(indices, train_indices)]
   1590         else:
-> 1591             X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
   1592 
   1593     if y is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
    161                                    indices.dtype.kind == 'i'):
    162             # This is often substantially faster than X[indices]
--> 163             return X.take(indices, axis=0)
    164         else:
    165             return X[indices]

IndexError: index 900 is out of bounds for size 900
```

**So, my question is which of the above approaches is the correct to compute [cross validated metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)?.** I believe that my scores are contaminated, since I am confused about when to perform cross validation. Thus, any idea of how to perform correctly cross validated scores?.

**UPDATE**

Evaluating in the training step?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = False)
clf = make_pipeline(SVC())
# However, fot clf, you can use whatever estimator you like
kf = StratifiedKFold(y = y_train, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=False)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv = kf, scoring='precision')
print('Mean score : ', np.mean(scores))
print('Score variance : ', np.var(scores))
```

Answer (score 4):

For any classification task its always good to use StratifiedKFold cross validation split. In stratified KFold, you have equal number of samples from each class for your classification problem.

[image: StratifiedKFold]

Then it depends on your type of classification problem. Its always good to see the precision and recall scores. In case of a skewed binary classification, people tend to use ROC AUC score:

```
from sklearn import metrics
metrics.roc_auc_score(ytest, ypred)
```

Lets look at your solution:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC

np.random.seed(1337)

X = np.random.rand(1000,5)

y = np.random.randint(0,2,1000)

kf = KFold(n=len(y), n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
pipe= make_pipeline(SVC(random_state=42))
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

print ('Precision',np.mean(cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision')))
# Here you are evaluating precision score on X_train.

#Second Approach
clf = SVC(random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print ('Precision:', precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='binary'))

# here you are evaluating precision score on X_test

#Third approach
pipe= make_pipeline(SVC())
print('Precision',np.mean(cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=kf, scoring='precision')))

# Here you are splitting the data again and evaluating mean on each fold
```

Thus, the results are different

Comment: Thanks for the help, with regards to the `cross_val_score`, do you know why I am getting different results and which is the correct way to compute them?.

Comment: it could be due to random seed. did you try setting the random_state parameter and see what happens?

Comment: yes, my random I did the following before even started: `np.random.seed(1337)`

Comment: There is nothing related to the seed. This is due to the fact that each approach is doing a different thing :) However, if the seed is not specified, you will end up with somehow small differences results at each cross validation and (very) sligthly different result in the mean of the cross validation. If it is the same seed, you will have the exact same results each time you run your experiment - which I don't advice for overfitting reasons.

Comment: Thanks, both answers are great, although I would like to accept both I will accept the one that have more votes.

Answer (score 3):

First, as explained in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) and shown in some [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_diabetes.html#example-exercises-plot-cv-diabetes-py), the `scikit-learn` cross-validation `cross_val_score` do the following :

1. Split your dataset `X` within N folds (according to the parameters `cv`). It splits the labels `y` accordingly.
2. Use the estimator (parameter `estimator`) to train it on N-1 previous folds.
3. Use the estimator to predict the labels of the last fold.
4. Returns a score (parameter `scoring`) by comparing the prediction and the true value
5. Repeat Step 2. to Step 4. by changing the testing fold. Thus, you end up with an array of N scores.

Let's take a look at each of your approach.

**First approach:**

Why would you split the training set before the cross_validation as the scikit-learn function does it for you? Thus, you train your model on less data, ending with a worth validation score

**Second approach:**

Here, you use another metric than `cross_validation_sore` on your data. Thus, you cannot compare it to the other validation score - because they are two different things. One is a classic percentage of error whereas `precision` is a metric used to calibrate binary classifier (true or false). This is a good metric though (you can check for ROC curves, and precision and recall metrics) but then compare only these metrics.

**Third approach:**

This one is the more natural one. This score is the *good* one (I mean if you want to compare it to other classifiers/estimators). However, I would warn you from taking the mean directly as a result. Because there are two things you can compare : the mean but also the variance. Each score of the array is different from the other and you might want to know by how much, compare to other estimators (You definitely want your variance as small as possible)

**Fourth approach:**

There seems to be a problem with the `Kfold` not related to the `cross_val_score`

**Finally:**

Use only the second **OR** the third approach to compare the estimators. But they definitely don't estimate the same thing - precision versus the error rate.

```
clf = make_pipeline(SVC())
# However, fot clf, you can use whatever estimator you like
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv = 10, scoring='precision')
print('Mean score : ', np.mean(scores))
print('Score variance : ', np.var(scores))
```

By changing the `clf` to another estimator (or integrating it into a loop), you would be able to have a score for each eastimator and compare them

Comment: Thanks for the help, with regards to the third approach im do not understand why i can't do: `cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=kf, scoring='precision')`, I get the follwing exception:`IndexError: index 900 is out of bounds for size 900`, why this is happening?

Comment: kf is on the full set, i.e. len(y), and you are using X_train, y_train there.

Comment: Yes, absolutely :) I think what you are trying to do is `cv = 10` (instead of `cv = kf`).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I am a bit confused... I read the docs and I did not understood which is the standard correct way... could anybody put an example?.

Comment: Thanks igor... finally, if I would like to set the `cv` with stratifiedkfold and I would like to evaluate in the testing step, how do I correctly perform such procedure?, should I do the updated procedure in the above question?

Comment: The doc states that `For integer/None inputs, if y is binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold used`. So by default, if `cv = 10` and your data represents classes, then StratifiedKFold is used by default. I didn't get the `I would like to evaluate in the testing step` - the testing step is integrated in the `cross_val_score` but if you want to do only one split, use `train_test_split` which is probably not a good practice here for cross-validation

Comment: I see... So... which is the correct way of spliting my data?...using the permutator or `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I think `cross_val_score` is well designed for what you are trying to do in case you want to compare estimators performances.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I will accept the answer who achieve 3 "likes"

Comment: You should accept the answer that you think is the right answer to your question and that helped you better according to your problem :)